Weird Survival curves with confidence intervals in R
My survival graph looks weird at the end of the curves. 
I checked my data, it has no negative values for the time-to-event variable. Time-to-event variable has values from 0-3266 days. There are no missing values for any columns. yet it produces such a weird graph. I have tried both 'log' and 'log-log' confidence interval types. I get the following error when I use 'log-log'
> # Calculate the confidence interval for each drug group
> survival_ci <- df %>%
+   group_by(DRUG_GROUP) %>%
+   do(tidy(survfit(Surv(T2_GI_BLED, POST_GI_BLEEDING) ~ 1, data = ., conf.int = TRUE, conf.type = "log-log")))
|==================================================================================================|100% ~0 s remaining     Warning messages:
1: In log(-log(xx)) : NaNs produced
2: In log(-log(xx)) : NaNs produced
3: In log(-log(xx)) : NaNs produced
4: In log(-log(xx)) : NaNs produced
5: In log(-log(xx)) : NaNs produced
6: In log(-log(xx)) : NaNs produced
7: In log(-log(xx)) : NaNs produced
8: In log(-log(xx)) : NaNs produced

but I get no error when I use 'log' confidence interval type, yet I get the same weird survival curve. Is there anything that I should double-check?
Here is my R code snippet:
# Filter out rows with missing values in relevant columns
df <- df %>%
  filter(!is.na(T2_GI_BLED) & !is.na(POST_GI_BLEEDING) & !is.na(DRUG_GROUP))

# Convert the data to a format used by the survival package
survival_data <- with(df, Surv(T2_GI_BLED, POST_GI_BLEEDING))

# Fit the survival data to a constant for each drug group
survival_fit <- df %>%
  group_by(DRUG_GROUP) %>%
  do(tidy(survfit(Surv(T2_GI_BLED, POST_GI_BLEEDING) ~ 1, data = .)))

# Calculate the confidence interval for each drug group
survival_ci <- df %>%
  group_by(DRUG_GROUP) %>%
  do(tidy(survfit(Surv(T2_GI_BLED, POST_GI_BLEEDING) ~ 1, data = ., conf.int = TRUE, conf.type = "log")))


Where’s your code to create the plot? Please provide that and the data you plot, so that your question is reproducible.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

I figured it. It was due to some events happening post study end date.
The following can be used to exclude them:
# Function to filter rows based on date columns
filter_rows_by_dates <- function(df, date_cols) {
  
  # Apply filter conditions using dplyr
  df_filtered <- df %>%
    filter(
      if_all(all_of(date_cols), ~ is.na(.) | . <= as.Date("2021-12-31"))
    )
  
  return(df_filtered)
}

# Apply the function to filter out rows with dates beyond '2021-12-31'
df_filtered <- filter_rows_by_dates(FINAL_DATA, date_columns)

